# Issue with basic PGP decryption - java

Tags: encryption, pgp

I have to implement a simple PGP decryption. Have decided to use 'BouncyCastle' as the provider.

i have the following things:
- test java code (which decrypts)
- the .asc file which needs to be decrypted
- the pass phrase

The test code which I downloaded via Google, excepts a private key ring. I do not have it. My question is, who will provide this private key ring or private secret key file? Or should I be generating it with my public key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recipient of the encrypted data gives you (the sender of the encrypted data) the public key and keeps his secret key, well, secret. You encrypt the data using given public key.

For test purposes you can generate a keypair and be your own recipient.

Comment: Problem here is I have the encrypted data (created by sender) which I need to decrypt. The secret key should be shared, i believe? to decrypt?

Comment: @user1134904 no, secret key must be kept secret. You need to create a keypair, give the public part of the keypair to the sender and ask him to encrypt the data using the given public key. Then you can decrypt it using the secret key from the generated keypair.

Comment: Ok,now I get it. I know my teammate shared the public key for encryption. I will ask him if he has the secret key.

Comment: @user1134904 he asks, but that is his secret key which he won't share with you.